# Android Bluetooth read specific string

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

My android program is now able to receive string like "Test" or "Test 123".
Now, I need to receive a specific strings for incoming data.

In example: **~100 *200 $300**.

How can I separate these 3 data by filtering the symbol, such as Textbox1 = "100", Textbox2 = "200" and Textbox3 = "300"?

Please help.

This is my current bluetooth code.

```
   private byte read()

    {

        byte dataRead = 0;


        try
        {
            dataRead = (byte) inputStream.read();
        }
        catch(IOException readException)
        {
            toastText = "Failed to read from input stream: " + readException.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(Trial_Blood_Pressure.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return dataRead;
    }

                if (flag)
                {
                    final byte data = read();

                    readMessageHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            String message;

                            if (data != 1){
                                /*  if(txtReceived.getText().toString().equals("ON") || txtReceived.getText().toString().equals("OFF"))
                                {
                                    txtReceived.setText("");
                                }*/
                                message = txtReceived.getText().toString() + (char)data;}

                            else{
                                message = "";}

                            txtReceived.setText(message);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Where is the code from `if (flag)` and afterwards located?

Also, I'm not quite sure what you want to do. You will be receiving strings in the format of '~100 *200 $300.' (with different numbers) and you want to separate them?

Comment: Thanks Der Golem. You answered my question. Thanks

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **same separator**. I.e.: `"100$200$300"`.
Then you can use `String.split()` to create a string array which contains the separate values.